# How to prevent an action extension from appearing in my own iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-extensions

I have an iOS app with an action extension that is used to perform actions on images inside other apps when they present `UIActivityViewController`. Everything is working as intended - if I present an activity sheet in another app, my action extension appears in the list alongside the system actions (such as *Save to Files* and *Create Watch Face* etc).

However, the action extension also appears in my own app when I present `UIActivityViewController` on an image there, which I do not want to happen. Is there any way to prevent my own action extension from appearing in `UIActivityViewController` inside my own app?

I've tried adding an entry to `excludedActivityTypes` when presenting `UIActivityViewController` as follows, but this did not work:

```
let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [media], applicationActivities: nil)
activity.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType("com.example.ActionExtensionIdentifier")]
// other setup code
present(activity, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that I finally used, in case anyone else needs this. (The code was taken from this blog post: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2016/hiding-action-share-extensions-in-your-own-apps/ so take a look at that too for more details, but the solution I've provided here contains everything that is required to make this work.)

**1. First, create this class**

```
class ActionExtensionBlockerItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        return String()
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return NSObject()
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> String {
        return String()
    }

    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return nil
    }

    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return String()
    }
}
```

**2. Apply instance of that class**

When you present `UIActivityViewController`, create an instance of `ActionExtensionBlockerItem` and include it in the `activityItems` array like this:

```
func share(_ image: UIImage) {
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image, ActionExtensionBlockerItem()], applicationActivities: nil)
    activity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view // change to something appropriate for your app
    activity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.bounds // change to something appropriate for your app
    present(activity, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, still showing "Copy to..." in activity view controller

Comment: Did you follow the guide in the pspdfkit link? There's more info in there.